# Why exchange server return different serverIds in MoveItems and Sync

Tags: exchange-server, activesync

I'm developing an email app used on cell phone.
When I delete a message with MoveItems command (move the message to "Deleted Items" folder), server returns a new ServerId of "3:3" for the message.
But when I sync the "Deleted Items" with Sync command, server returns a ServerId of "3:1" for the same message.
This causes two messages with identical content but different ServerId in the "Deletd Items" folder.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In ActiveSync, the server-assigned item IDs can change whenever a Sync occurs. It's frustrating to code against that, but the IDs assigned by Exchange are ephemeral and will frequently change.

Whenever significant changes are made to a Folder that requires a Sync, you have to guard against the ID changes by essentially clearing your current cached version of that folder's contents and replace it with what the server sends you. Correlating the new items to the old ones is very difficult, because ActiveSync offers no persistent unique identifier that travels with each item, AFAIK. Exchange Web Services (EWS) is more flexible in this regard and you can do it with that API.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716926/how-to-get-the-new-message-id-after-a-sync-delete-request?rq=1

Comment: any idea if this answer is still true in all later versions of EAS?

Comment: to answer my own question, in case others have it: version 16.1 now should have stable server ids across syncs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-ascmd/a875f1e4-37ae-4ec3-832f-2e1867c13c0a?redirectedfrom=MSDN